# Why is body class overriding footer html

Tags: html, css

I am curious why would the second color get over-written by the first one?  Is there a way around this by not adding `!important` or wrapping it in the body class?

```
body.football h3 {
   color: #a07a40;
}

footer h3 {
   color: white;
}
```

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is getting overridden because css will use the most specific selector over any other selector.

To resolve this you will either need to use the `!important` flag or change the footer selector to be more specific, the easiest way to do that is use an id.

An Example:

```
#footer h3{
    color: white;
}

<footer id='footer'><h3></h3></footer>
```

Answer (score 6):

Cascading stylesheets go by a hierarchical scheme if two selectors exist targeting the same element. The more specific one will take precedence.

However, your body probably should not have a class on it like that, just as a best practice. It's begging for headaches.

Your options:

Quick and dirty, you can use a descendant selector `>` to specify the immediate child. For instance:

```
body.football > h3 {
   color: #a07a40;
}

footer > h3 {
   color: white;
}

<body class="football">
    <h3>Football is the Bees Knees</h3>
    <footer>
        <h3>Hi Ma Hi Pa</h3>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Alternately, per your OP, you can also wrap the body content in a section or div and apply styles to that, IE:

```
section#football h3 {
   color: #a07a40;
}

footer h3 {
   color: white;
}

<body>
    <section id="football">
        <h3>Football Yo</h3>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <h3>Yo Football</h3>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Edit: I should add that the empty space between the two elements means that you're going to hit ALL the elements that are descendants of the parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

CSS likes to prefer more specific declarations over less specific declarations. Without seeing accompanying HTML it may be a little hard to be sure, but it is most likely because your body.football declaration is more  specific.

Answer (score 0):

There is html mistake on writed code or css structure.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="football">
        <h3>ho</h3>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <h3>test</h3>
    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body.football h3 {
   color: #a07a40;
}

footer h3 {
   color: red;
}
```

Example on  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjhk7wcd/1/).

Or if football is on footer section, then you need put a class.

```
footer h3 {
   color: red;
}

footer .football h3 {
   color: #a07a40;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjhk7wcd/4/)